# lighttpd php5 socket_connect() permission denied

Tags: php, linux, sockets, lighttpd

I'm trying to connect to a unix socket in php on a linux machine. It's a micro controller, so i decided to use lighttpd to get the server up and running. I'm having a problem connecting to a socket which another app is listening to though.

in PHP i create a socket using socket_create() passing AF_UNIX as the first argument, then i try to connect to the socket using socket_connect(), which is getting a permission denied error which i found using socket_last_error().

Another application is listening on the socket for new connections, and i'm able to connect to it through sockets with another application, but i'm getting permission denied in php.

the code looks like this:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $sockaddr);
echo socket_last_error();
```

lighttpd is running under the user "www-data", which is in the groups sudo, adm, and www-data.

To tell you the truth, even after a lot of googling i don't know where to go from here.

There is no selinux, so the answers that mention using setsebool won't work because there is no setsebool command

lighttpd does not use apache, so none of the answers relating to apache will work either because there is no apache.

how do i give lighttpd or php5 permission to connect to a socket?

php5 is using fastcgi if that matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was having permission issues accessing /tmp/socketname. The work around I found that worked was to have php execute a chmod command on the file before creating the socket:

```
$sockaddr = "/tmp/socketname";
$command = "sudo chmod go+w ".$sockaddr;
exec($command);
```